# EnumThreadWindows return value

Tags: c++, winapi

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495(VS.85).aspx) specifies the return value for `EnumThreadWindows` as:

> If the callback function returns **TRUE** for all windows in the thread specified by *dwThreadId*, the return value is **TRUE**. If the callback function returns **FALSE** on any enumerated window, or if there are no windows found in the thread specified by *dwThreadId*, the return value is **FALSE**.

But, the code I write behaves exactly opposite. According to documentation, this snippet must return `TRUE` only when there are windows associated with the thread:

```
BOOL test = EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), [](HWND, LPARAM) {
    return TRUE;
}, NULL);

// test is always TRUE
// expected it to be TRUE when there are windows, FALSE otherwise
```

On the other hand, this code snippet must always return `FALSE` according the the reference, but strangely, it returns `FALSE` when there are windows, and `TRUE` when there is no window:

```
BOOL test = EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), [](HWND, LPARAM) {
    return FALSE;
}, NULL);

// test is TRUE if no window exists, FALSE otherwise
// expected it to always be FALSE
```

If you swap **TRUE** and **FALSE** in the spec, then the codes behaves correctly. Am I doing something wrong or is the documentation really incorrect?

Comment: He does pass 3 arguments, 3rd is NULL, code with a lambda function is not always easy to read :)

Comment: But yes, I repro on Windows 10.0.10586.  No idea how long this quirk has been around, I never relied on the return value before.  Best if you don't either :)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks.

Comment: Does the thread in question have any windows? I expect that `EnumThreadWindows` may return `TRUE` when there are no windows associated with the thread (thus, no callback is actually invoked). Also, you should hope that the lambda routine has `stdcall` calling convention.

Comment: @MartinDrab The documentation says _"if there are no windows found in the thread specified by dwThreadId, the return value is FALSE"_ why would you expect it to return `true`?

Comment: @MartinDrab  I have tested with and without windows, and the results are as posted above. If I inspect the HWND passed to the callback, it's always correct, I can count the number of windows inside the callback, etc. It's only the return value of `EnumThreadWindows` that's unexpected.

Comment: @MartinDrab Regarding calling convention: [The Visual C++ compiler automatically provides conversions for every calling convention](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150220-00/?p=44623/).

Comment: Thanks for the corrections

Comment: yes, this is really documentation incorrect. if thread have no windows or any other error `EnumThreadWindows` return `dwThreadId != 0` - so usually TRUE. interesting that we can set dwThreadId as 0 in first parameter. in this case will be all windows belong to current desktop enumerated (i check this from xp sp3 to win 10) - however nothing about this feature in documentation )